# Codeigniter - Multifile plugin?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a php application that doesn't use the mvc model that i would like to add to my codeigniter app as an plugin only issue is the CI documentation seems like it only supports one file plugins. What is the best way to go about implementing an extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CI has no solution to this. The reason is that trying to shove one application into another application is like trying to have two people drive. Both people will be bumping up next to each other, and trying to accomplish the goal of driving will be a balancing act between both.

The exception would be HMVC because it is designed to have multiple MVC instances within each, along with well namespaced applications like CI. There should be minimal conflict if you put CI within another application for the most part.

It really isn't the best practice, but if you insist on going down this approach I would use a controller as the bootstrap or index for the other application. Put the rest of the other application as a folder in CI to avoid conflicts with CI. You would probably have to tweak the paths a bit, as well as rework the URLs.